Movie about a jewish boy who becomes white supremacist and neo-nazi
I dont remember much about this movie. Its about a boy, i think late teens or early twenties. He gets turned off of his jeiwsh school after a disagreement with his teacher. Becomes white supremacist and neo-nazi and joins a gang who plots to blow up a synagogue on Yom Kippur. At the end he regrets and evacuate the synagogue on time, but stays to die by himself.

Why the downvote? Whats wrong with the question?

Hi Mennyg. Please read the last section here. Your question is currently missing many details that are required from ID questions on M&TV.SE.

This film stars Ryan Gosling and it is titled "The Believer."
Plot from IMBD:

"The Believer" explores a Jewish student's private journey to
  understand the meaning of Judaism in his life. Set in New York City,
  the Plot follows a morally confused young adult struggling with the
  conflict between his beliefs and his heritage. "The Believer" examines
  themes of religion, family, and self-loathing. It is a psychological
  examination into the forces of intolerance, both on the individual and
  society as a whole.

